# Confirmation alert before app close - Ionic2 using typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I make one application with IONIC-2 Beta version.I am trying to get alert before close the application.

In previous version of ionic 2 I used,

[This Code](http://ionicguru.blogspot.in/2015/12/show-confirmation-alert-before-app-close.html)

but in newer version this is not working.

How it is work with Type Script + ionic 2?

Answer (score 1):

You have to register hardwarebackbuttonaction in app.component.ts like this:

```
platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
    if(this.nav.canGoBack()){
        this.nav.pop();
    }else{
      if(isAlertShowing){
        //dismiss alert
      }else{
        //show alert
      }
    }
  });
```